# The last element in the row BrowseFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tv, leanback

I have a Fragment:

```
public class FilmFragment extends BrowseFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Object>
```

In **BrowseFragment** I add several rows with items:

```
private void loadRubricsFilms(List<Rubric> mRubrics, List<Film> mFilms) {
    int j = 0;

    for (Rubric mRubric : mRubrics) {
        ArrayObjectAdapter listRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(mCardPresenter);

        for (Film mFilm : mFilms) {
            if (mFilm.getRubric() == mRubric.getId()) {
                listRowAdapter.add(mFilm);
            }
        }
        HeaderItem header = new HeaderItem(j++, mRubric.getTitle());
        mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(header, listRowAdapter));
    }
    setAdapter(mRowsAdapter);
}
```

I installed **OnItemViewSelectedListener** listener:

```
    private final class ItemViewSelectedListener implements OnItemViewSelectedListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(Presenter.ViewHolder itemViewHolder, Object item,
                               RowPresenter.ViewHolder rowViewHolder, Row row) {
    }
}

    setOnItemViewSelectedListener(new ItemViewSelectedListener());
```

override method **onItemSelected**:

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(Presenter.ViewHolder itemViewHolder, Object item,
                               RowPresenter.ViewHolder rowViewHolder, Row row) {
    }
```

I need to detect when the last item in the row is selected. How do I determine it?

Comment: Incomplete question, please put your whole code, and be more specific about your problem.

Comment: Added additional methods in question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all the information you need out of the `Row row`, `Object item`, and the `ArrayObjectAdapter` on the `Row` that are handed back in the `onItemSelected(...)` event.

Something like:

```
final ListRow listRow = (ListRow) row;
final ArrayObjectAdapter currentRowAdapter = listRow.getAdapter();
int selectedIndex = currentRowAdapter.indexOf(item);
if (selectedIndex != -1 && (currentRowAdapter.size() - 1) == selectedIndex ) {
    // The last item was selected
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But there is no method of class `Row` `getArrayAdapter ()`.

Comment: I just made an edit to fix the issue. The [`ListRow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/ListRow.html) has the `getAdapter()` method. You might want to wrap the cast in an `instanceof` check just to be sure, but based on this line: `mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(header, listRowAdapter));`, you should be safe.

Comment: **Everything is working! Thank you so much!** P.S. Corrected the name of the variable index in the `if` block.